# Selenium returning a false after screenshot being captured

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, selenium-webdriver-python

Whenever I am trying to capture a screenshot from Selenium and trying to save the screenshot to a specified folder, it is returning false.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(os.getcwd()+"/PermitSide/"+folio_number+".png")
```

However when I save the screenshot with the following command it is being saved and returning true.

```
driver.save_screenshot('ss.png')
```

I have already made the PermitSide folder and yet the screenshots are not being saved there.

Code trials:

```
driver.get('https://w85exp.miamidade.gov/permitInqWeb/folioStatus/get_folio_inq.jsp?folioNumber=' + folio_number)

#Take data from config file
file = open('configps.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
folio_number = lines[0]

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

#Find elements and take snapshots
elementID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input')
elementID.send_keys(folio_number)

S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
#driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').save_screenshot(os.getcwd()+"/PermitSide/"+folio_number+".png")
```

Answer (score 1):

### save_screenshot()

[save_screenshot()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot) is a method from the he [WebDriver implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver).

Where as you are trying to use the [screenshot(filename)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.screenshot) from the [remote webelement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)

---

### This usecase

Presumably, the variable *folio_number* is an integer, so you won't be able to append an *integer variable* directly within an *string variable*. First you need to convert the *integer variable* to *string variable* as follows:

```
folio_number = 123
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(os.getcwd()+"/PermitSide/"+str(folio_number)+".png")
```

---

### Update

With a config file like:

[image: config]

The following code takes a proper screenshot:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
file = open('config.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
folio_number = lines[0]
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(os.getcwd()+"/PermitSide/"+str(folio_number)+".png")
```

Screenshot:

[image: 12345]

Comment: It is saying: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'save_screenshot'

Comment: @Daremitsu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: Are you sure _`folio_number`_ variable is present? How is _`folio_number`_ defined?

Comment: Added code base for clarification. folio_number is the data in the txt file and we are using the folio_number as the name for the png

Comment: @Daremitsu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Checked the updated answer. It is still coming false.

Comment: @Daremitsu Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240674/discussion-between-daremitsu-and-debanjanb).

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.